# pytorch: Instance norm implemented by basic operations has different result comparing to torch.nn.InstanceNorm2d

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

I implement instance norm by pytorch basic operations from scratch. But the result is different from torch.nn.InstanceNorm2d. Can anyone help me out? Below is my code:

```
import torch
import numpy as np
x = torch.rand((8, 16, 32, 32))
a = torch.nn.InstanceNorm2d(256)
a.eval()
with torch.no_grad():
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;b = a(x)
x_mean = torch.mean(x, axis=(2,3), keepdims=True)
x_var = torch.var(x, axis=(2,3), keepdims=True)
x_norm = (x - x_mean) / torch.sqrt(x_var + 1e-5)
b_numpy = b.numpy()
x_norm_numpy = x_norm.numpy()
\# check if b_numpy and x_norm_numpy close to the torlerance of 1e-3
print(np.allclose(b_numpy, x_norm_numpy, atol=1e-3))
\# check if b_numpy and x_norm_numpy close to the torlerance of 1e-3
print(np.allclose(b_numpy, x_norm_numpy, atol=1e-4))
```

Result:

```
True
False
```

So, the result shows that when precision comes to 1e-4, they are different. I don’t know why. Can anyone help me to get a more close result to `torch.nn.InstanceNorm2d`?

BTW, the reason why I do not use formula `gamma * x_normalized_numpy + beta` in the paper is I find that when the first initialization of `torch.nn.InstanceNorm2d`, all gamma is initialized to `[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, …]` and all beta is initialized to `[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, …]`. So, under this condition, `x_normalized_numpy = gamma * x_normalized_numpy + beta`

Answer (score 0):

PyTorch's implementation of Instance Norm [uses the biased variance estimate](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.InstanceNorm2d.html).

Try using `torch.var(x, axis=(2,3), keepdims=True, unbiased=False)`.